# Bluetooth does not see a device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I create app which work with bluetooth and almost everything is ok but one this is not cool. So after I connect device do some staff save everything them disconnect it, my app stops seeing this device is no more on my list, but after 5-10 minutes device back on the list. What can be the issue?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int SEND_TIMES = 1;
static final int SEND_DATE = 2;

List<BluetoothDevice> devices;
Spinner devicesSpinner = null;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothSocket clientSocket = null;
OutputStream outputData = null;
InputStream inputData = null;
List<String> devicesNames = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableRequest = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableRequest);
    }

    findDevices();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(deviceFoundReceiver, filter);
    registerReceiver(bondStateChangeReceiver, filter);

    devices = new ArrayList();
    devicesSpinner = findViewById(R.id.devices_list);


    devicesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            try {
                if(devices.get(i) == null)
                    return;
                BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(devices.get(i).getAddress());
                Method m = remoteDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
                clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(remoteDevice, 1);
                outputData = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                inputData = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("REMOTE_DEVICE", "No such a method", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView<?> adapterView){
        }
    });
    if(clientSocket != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + clientSocket.isConnected(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

public void connectDevice(View view) throws IOException {
    if (isSocketConnected()) return;
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    if(!clientSocket.isConnected()){

        try {
            clientSocket.connect();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not connect to this device try later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boundedDevice);
        textView.setText(clientSocket.getRemoteDevice().getName());
    }
}

public void disconnectDevice(View view) throws IOException {
    if(clientSocket.isConnected()){
        clientSocket.close();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boundedDevice);
        textView.setText("Device not connected");
    }
}
```

}

That is my code which I am using for connection, what is wrong?

What I want to have is I would like to have my device straight away on my list after disconnection, to not waiting those 5-10 mins to let my app find it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is client-side code and you need server-side code.So you need two device and one device must be a server another device must be a client.If you want to search available device you work in server side.First of all you must look at android developer bluetooth chat project in the official site.Then find out server-side code.

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/project.html